# How do I block all the browser extensions from running on my Node web app?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, next.js, browser

I made this web app in Next.js, made it a PWA and I noticed that if a person has the google translate browser extension (on their cellphone for instance) when you open up the PWA it then automatically translates what you type in the web app main input field, or the menu voices, etc.

Is there any way to avoid extensions to run on a Node web app?

Do I need to attach some code for this question to be valid? if so what code do you need?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem -**

Your PWA built with Next.js is being auto-translated, and you want to block the user from doing this.

**Overview -**

Node is the backend service you are using to support your front end. The front end is built with React.js.

**Solution -**

You cannot stop a user from translating a webpage or PWA. When the app loads on the user's device, they have complete control over what happens from that point on. I am not aware that installing Chrome extensions is possible on a phone, but you can turn on the setting in your Chrome mobile app to auto-translate a webpage to your preferred language.

**Closing -**

In summary, you cannot stop a user from translating your PWA, nor can you block a user's Chrome extensions programmatically.